# Clicking a link in an iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe, dom-events

Is it possible to click a link on an external site that's loaded in an iframe, using a JavaScript? The link is:

```
<a href="#" onclick=Center.Add('micro1')>micro</a>
```

```
<div id="frameContainer"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
onload=function(){
var el=document.getElementById("frameContainer")
el.innerHTML="<iframe border=\"0\" scrolling=no src=\"http://example.com/en-US/My/Pro?tag=micro1\"></iframe>"
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page loaded in the iframe is from a different domain? You want to execute JavaScript in the child frame from the parent frame? If so, then the answer is no. Security issues prevent cross-domain JavaScript.

There are work-arounds if both pages are "yours". But if not then the answer is a definite no.

Comment: are there any other methods that you might know of? I've tried ajax no luck, tried parsing the actual link from the other domain and putting it on my site, no luck with that. The site i'm working with does not provide an api

Comment: It depends on exactly what you want to do. Something you can do is use a PHP proxy on your domain that reads the external URL as a string, adds a `base` tag so that all images, etc. load correctly then echos the string. This has the effect of loading an external URL as a page on your domain. Then you can execute scripts in the child frame from the parent form since it is no longer on an external domain.